# Add New Datagridview Columns From Database Columns Values And Display Data

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, datagridview

anyone can help me with my project?

Note: This is what I want to achieve..
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDhpn.png)

Note: This is currently what I got..
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Jwfl.png)

Table 1: prod_pricelvl (Cols: id, desc)

This is where I stored the price category like COGS, LP, SRP which I use as a list to add columns in the datagridview so that it will automatically add new columns in datagridview whenever I add new category for product pricing.

*Current Stored Values

- 1, COGS
- 2, LP
- 3, SRP

Table 2: prod_price (Cols: id, date, prodCode, priceLvl, uPrice)

This is where the prices are stored.

*Current Stored Values

- 1, 02/04/2024, Test001, COGS, 7650
- 2, 02/04/2024, Test001, LP, 8500
- 3, 02/04/2024, Test001, SRP, 8925

Current Code I Have....

```
Private Sub ShowPriceHistory()
    Try
        Using conn As New SQLiteConnection(conStr)
          conn.Open()

          Dim colQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM prod_pricelvl"
          Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand(colQuery, conn)
            Using dr As SQLiteDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
              DgPriceHistory.Columns.Clear()
              DgPriceHistory.Columns.Add("date", "DATE")

              While dr.Read()
                Dim columnName As String = dr("description").ToString()
                DgPriceHistory.Columns.Add(columnName, columnName)
              End While
            End Using
          End Using

          Dim dataQuery As String = "SELECT date, uPrice FROM prod_price WHERE prodCode = '" & TxtCode.Text & "'"
          Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand(dataQuery, conn)
            Using dr As SQLiteDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
              While dr.Read()
                Dim row As New DataGridViewRow()
                row.CreateCells(DgPriceHistory)

                For i As Integer = 0 To dr.FieldCount - 1
                  row.Cells(i).Value = dr.GetValue(i)
                Next

                DgPriceHistory.Rows.Add(row)
              End While
            End Using
          End Using

          conn.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

I manage to add new columns based on what values stored in table prod_priceLvl, now what i want is to display the date and price in one row only that corresponds on column name price level.

Comment: Try styling the datagridview FIRST then add the data where you want it may need a condition statement for adding data